# I can't use PHP from with HTML table

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I have created a form that works fine, but when I put it in a table I does not work. No data in the assign.php when I click the assign task button.
The reason that made me use the table is that I'm trying to find a way that can make the form looks nice.

-----My HTML------

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="assign.php" method="post">
<table align="center" >
    <tr><td>Annotator:</td><td><SELECT name="annotator">
                               <option value= Adam >Adam</option>
                                </select></td></tr></br></br>

    <tr><td>Dialect:</td><td><SELECT name="dialect">
                             <option value= USA >USA</option>
                              </select></td></tr></br></br>

    <tr><td>Enter number of blogs:</td><td><INPUT type="text" name="numberofblogs"></td><td><div style = "color: grey"><I> blogs</I></div></td></tr>

    <tr><td>Percntage:</td><td><INPUT type="text" name="rednum"></td><td><div style = "color: grey"><I> % </I></div></td></tr>

    <tr><td></br></br><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Assign Task"></td></tr>
</table>
```

-----My PHP------

```
<html>
<body>
 <?php  
   $annotator=$_POST["annotator"]; 
   $dialect=$_POST["dialect"];
   $numberofblogs= $_POST["numberofblogs"]; 
   $rednum=$_POST["rednum"];

   print "Name of annotator: ". $annotator ."<br>";
   print "Dialect: ". $dialect ."<br>";
   print "Total number of blogs is". $numberofblogs ."<br>";
   print "Percentage". $rednum ."<br>";
   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The </form> is missing ?

Comment: add </form> before table close

Comment: Total mess, no `</form>`, no quotes around `option` values, combination of upper and lowercase tags also, `br` is wrong, it should be `<br>` or `<br />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some errors found:
- no closing tag for form.
- used **br** outside **tr** tag which is wrong.

----HTML FORM----

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="assign.php" method="post">
      <table align="center" >
        <tr>
          <td>Annotator:</td>
          <td>
            <select name="annotator">
              <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dialect:</td>
          <td>
            <select name="dialect">
              <option value="USA">USA</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enter number of blogs:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="numberofblogs"></td>
          <td><div style = "color: grey;"><I> blogs</I></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Percentage:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rednum"></td>
          <td><div style = "color: grey"><I> % </I></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></br></br><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Assign Task"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---PHP Page---

```
<html>
  <body>
   <?php  
     $annotator=$_POST["annotator"]; 
     $dialect=$_POST["dialect"];
     $numberofblogs= $_POST["numberofblogs"]; 
     $rednum=$_POST["rednum"];

     print "Name of annotator: ". $annotator ."<br>";
     print "Dialect: ". $dialect ."<br>";
     print "Total number of blogs is". $numberofblogs ."<br>";
     print "Percentage". $rednum ."<br>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think they know how, with zero accepted answers on their four questions?  They just got here; may help to actually instruct them how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

See besic html syntax of select : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Add form close tag, you missed quotation in option values fix it  and it should be working :)

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <form action="assign.php" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Annotator:</td>
                <td><SELECT name="annotator">
                        <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Dialect:</td>
                <td><SELECT name="dialect">
                        <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Enter number of blogs:</td>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="numberofblogs"></td>
                <td>
                    <div style="color: grey"><I> blogs</I></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Percntage:</td>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="rednum"></td>
                <td>
                    <div style="color: grey"><I> % </I></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><br /><br /><input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Assign Task"></td>
            </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This misses some key facts.

Comment: @user3001418 : did you test it?

Comment: @Daedalus :  bro i did not tag you and can you please explain me what have i missed? there will be something to learn :)

Comment: Read the top voted answer and you'll see.  Your answer is giving invalid html.

Comment: @Daedalus: yes there are <br> issues. actually question was not submitting form. so i was looking for this cause. and i have got html basic from w3school

Comment: Perpetuating incorrect information helps no one.  The least you can do is fix the error, instead of perpetuating it.

Comment: @Daedalus: i have edited my answer. there are also some issue with top voted answer. he did not indicate the quotation problem in option

Comment: You still have two more false break tags.  The correct break tag is either without a slash: `<br>`, or with the slash at the end `<br />`, as it has no opening slash; right now, your code reflects that there should be an opening slash, when in reality it does not exist.

Comment: Lastly, there is no quotation problem.  It's valid html, as [attributes may be unquoted](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#attributes-2).

Answer (score 0):

Its working from here. Please check the webserver is working or not.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: That would be because your browser fixed the invalid html.  That doesn't make this a right answer, though.